# SVG loading animation - can I combine <use>and <def> and <animate>?

Tags: svg, svg-animate

I have an SVG-based loading animation, aka "[spinning weasel](http://www.google.com/search?q=spinning%20weasel)" but I'm wondering if I can code this more efficiently by utilizing a base animation (the fading out attributes) and referencing it in my `<use>` tags?

```
      <defs>
        <line 
            id="bit"
            x1="50" 
            y1="25" 
            x2="50" 
            y2="10"  
            stroke="#000000">
        </line>
    </defs>
<g>
    <use 
            xlink:href="#bit" 
            opacity="0.8"
            transform="rotate(0 50 50)">
            <animate 
                attributeName="opacity"
                values="1;0.2" 
                dur="2.4s" 
                repeatCount="indefinite"
                begin="0.0s" 
            />
        </use>
    </g>
```

There are 12 of these `<use>` tags, I omitted them here for brevity. in the animation tag, **only** the `begin` attribute changes each time, the rest is identical.

I tried various approaches that seemed reasonable to me, but none work, so I'm hoping some SVG guru here can point me in the right direction. Or am I basically forced to repeat all the animation attributes on each of the  tags?

Knowing just a little about SVG, I realize that there are many ways to accomplish the same result.

Thanks.

### [--> Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b7cmF/1/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can do exactly what you are trying to do because `begin` is an attribute of the animation elements and not a property that can be inherited from a use.

Depending on what you mean by "more efficient", there are other ways to achieve a similar effect.  For example, you can use scripting:

http://jsfiddle.net/rzAwV/1/

This is a smaller file, but the animation is not as smooth because we are just rotating the spinner, rather than animating the opacity.

Comment: interesting. I also noticed you changed the way the spinner is made by cloning 4 elements.

Comment: Love the nested groups. but why wouldnt you just animate the spinner, without scripting, inside the SVG? I just tried it (doesn't work, but I don't think it's because it shouldn't)

Comment: Because AFAIK you can't animate in discrete steps.  But I am not an animation expert so maybe there is a way to do it I don't know about.

Comment: Correction: you can do it without scripting. See here: http://jsfiddle.net/cH7GY/